# Delete record with nil id in rails console heroku ruby postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I used destroy to delete a record remotely in heroku rails console and now it does not show up if I write

```
 MyModel.find_by(email: 'some@email.com')
```

but it does show up if I write

```
MyModel.find_by_or_create_by(email: 'some@email.com')
```

...except the id is nil. I can't figure out how to get rid of this record. I am using postgres and rails 4

When I try to create a new record with the same email via the web ui, it triggers the uniqueness validation for this ghost record...yet I can't remove the ghost record.

Comment: I think its soft deleted. Check if there any soft deletion gems installed if so try find by including the deleted records scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `find_or_create_by` returns a record with a nil `id`, that suggests the `find` part is failing, and then the `create` part fails too with validation errors. What do you get from `MyModel.find_or_create_by(email: 'some@email.com').errors.full_messages`? I'm guessing you see the same uniqueness validation error as you're seeing in the web console.

Is your app using a soft-delete approach, e.g. with a gem like `acts_as_paranoid` or `permanent_records`? Those gems change the behavior of `destroy` so that it does not issue a SQL `DELETE` command but instead sets a `deleted_at` column. They also hide soft-deleted records, so that may be why `find_by` isn't giving you anything. If this is what you're doing, you should make sure your uniqueness validation knows to ignore soft-deleted records. How to do that depends on your soft-delete implementation, but you might find [some](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia/issues/31) [tips](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia/issues/114) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957845/using-acts-as-paranoid-plugin-for-soft-delete-what-about-validations).

You might want to try straight SQL to see what's really in your database, e.g. using the Heroku psql prompt or this Ruby code: `MyModel.unscoped.where(email: "some@email.com")`

Comment: Yes.  acts_as_paranoid was the culprit

Answer (score 0):

`find_or_create_by` will look for the record by the given parameters and create it if it can't be found. If there isn't an id field that means it isn't being saved and your problem is already solved.

Comment: It is not solved, as I can neither save the record I find or create a new one via the web interface.  I have a uniqueness validation set on the email field and this record without an id prevents a new record with the same email from being created.